# PHP MS SQL Placeholders for Date

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

How do I pass date into placeholder for PHP and MS SQL?

The sample code I am using:

```
$fromDate = '2013-01-01';
$toDate = '2013-02-28';
$empno = 12345;

$sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM histTable WHERE EmpNum = ?
           AND toDate >= ? AND fromDate <= ?";

$sqlResult = $this->db->query($sqlStr, $empno, $fromDate, $toDate);
```

I could not get anything from the database unless I hard code the date values.

Can anyone please help?

Thank you.

Comment: im guessing your mysql has column as datatype or timestamp and your passing a string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435109/sql-query-escaping-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
$fromDate = '2013-01-01 00:00:00';
$toDate = '2013-02-28 00:00:00';
$empno = 12345;

$sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM histTable WHERE EmpNum = $empno
           AND toDate >= '$fromDate' AND fromDate <= '$toDate'";

$sqlResult = $this->db->query($sqlStr);
```

Comment: Wish I could but I have to use placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

Straight off the top of my head, try changing:

```
$sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM histTable WHERE EmpNum = ? AND toDate >= ? AND fromDate <= ?";
```

to

```
$sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM histTable WHERE EmpNum = ? AND toDate >= '?' AND fromDate <= '?'";
```

Answer (score 0):

its all in the '' or "" i rather to use "";

```
$fromDate = '2013-01-01';
$toDate = '2013-02-28';
$empno = 12345;

$sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM histTable WHERE EmpNum = ?
       AND toDate >= '{$fromDate}' AND fromDate <= '{$toDate}' ";

$sqlResult = $this->db->query($sqlStr, $empno, $fromDate, $toDate);
```

mind the commas around the vars.