# Prevent SQL Injection in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

does CI Active Record Prevent SQL Injection?

here's my code

```
    $this->db->select('t.DateTime,
                       su.FirstName,
                       su.MiddleName,
                       su.LastName,
                       l.Description,
                       t.Temperature,
                       t.UnitID,
                       t.Humidity');
    $this->db->from('temperaturelogs as t');
    $this->db->join('systemusers as su', 'su.UserID = t.Encoder');
    $this->db->join('locations as l', 't.LocationID = l.LocationID');
    $this->db->where("Cast(t.DateTime as date) >= '$start_date'");
    $this->db->where("Cast(t.DateTime as date) <= '$end_date'");
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

when I tried to Enter this Input in `End Date`.

**My Input:**
`'; Truncate Table systemusers; #`

**Gives me this error:**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'truncate table systemusers; #'' at line 6
>
> SELECT `t`.`DateTime`, `su`.`FirstName`, `su`.`MiddleName`,
>   `su`.`LastName`, `l`.`Description`, `t`.`Temperature`, `t`.`UnitID`,
>   `t`.`Humidity` FROM `temperaturelogs` as `t` JOIN `systemusers` as
>   `su` ON `su`.`UserID` = `t`.`Encoder` JOIN `locations` as `l` ON
>   `t`.`LocationID` = `l`.`LocationID` WHERE Cast(t.DateTime as date) >=
>   '2016-03-21' AND Cast(t.DateTime as date) <= ''; truncate table
>   systemusers; #'

the error doesn't have any relevant to my question...

Comment: which CI version are you using `echo CI_VERSION;` ?

Comment: @Viral i'm using the latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
$this->db->where('Cast(t.DateTime as date) >=', $start_date);
$this->db->where('Cast(t.DateTime as date) <=', $end_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$this->db->escape($start_date);` in your where clause.

Have a look on following [SQL query escaping + codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435109/sql-query-escaping-codeigniter)

Your Active Query would then become something like this

```
$this->db->select('t.DateTime,
                       su.FirstName,
                       su.MiddleName,
                       su.LastName,
                       l.Description,
                       t.Temperature,
                       t.UnitID,
                       t.Humidity');
    $this->db->from('temperaturelogs as t');
    $this->db->join('systemusers as su', 'su.UserID = t.Encoder');
    $this->db->join('locations as l', 't.LocationID = l.LocationID');
    $this->db->where("Cast(t.DateTime as date) >= '".$this->db->escape($start_date)"'");
    $this->db->where("Cast(t.DateTime as date) <= '".$this->db->escape($end_date)"'");
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: but I am using `Active Record`.

Comment: That's fine, you can still use variables in it. I have updated my response to include your query.

Comment: but I use `$this->input->post()`.. does this not escape the date?

Comment: Well syntax error says something else. Regardless, I think you should also put extra validations for data types. $start_date/$end_date in this case before you use it in your active query directly.

Comment: yes... but this solves my problem... I thought `$this->input->post()` escapes the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

**CodeIgniter** provides you to set custom key/value method in sql where clause using the following given method.

You can include an operator in the first parameter in order to control the comparison:

> $this->db->where('name !=', $name);
>   $this->db->where('id <', $id);
>   // Produces: WHERE name != 'Joe' AND id < 45